# Which library to use for FT232H, libMPSSE vs libFTDI or something else?

Tags: ftdi, c++, library

I have an FT232H chip, which supports a max SPI speed of 30 Mhz, I am interested in writing a library which uses the maximum speed of FT232H. And control 4-5 GPIO pins at the same time.

I have come across two libraries, [libFTDI](https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/) from Intra2net, and [libMPSSE](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-SPI.htm). I am having a difficult time choosing which library to rely on.

1. **Officialness**: libMPSSE is official and works out of the box. Whereas libFTDI doesn't seem to be that official and is maintained on a private git?
2. **Driver Requirement**: libMPSSE works with an MS Windows Certified Driver that is tested. Whereas libFTDI you need to switch to libUSB and work with that.
3. **Maintainance**: libMPSSE has a source that has been distributed as a zip file, with no official host. And no recent release. I believe I can pinpoint the latest version to be ~2015/16. libFTDI has a recent release as new as 7 July 2020 with version 1.5.

I am conflicted to decide which one to go for. What are the recommendations that you might have for me to choose one way or another? Importantly are there any other options.

**Summary**: libFTDI or libMPSSE or is there any other library I need to consider while working with FT232H to make a production quality code?

Comment: As a heads up: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442388/remove-time-gaps-before-chip-select-disabled-on-ftdi SPI can clock with 30 MHz but the FTx232H devices cannot maintain the speed without interruptions.